# ESP8266 Arduino and Rotary Encoder

Tags: arduino-uno, esp8266, interrupt, rotary-encoder

I'm trying to use the sketch bellow to work with my [WeMos D1 mini](https://cdn.instructables.com/FG7/9S89/INUV37ZY/FG79S89INUV37ZY.LARGE.jpg) (ESP8266 Arduino platform) together with Rotary Encoder [KY-040](https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/6193po2kMUL._SX425_.jpg) or [MJKDZ](https://ae01.alicdn.com/kf/HTB1TmD2SpXXXXXKXVXXq6xXFXXXN.jpg), and it's not working for some reason, but the same sketch is working great on the Arduino Uno (with different pin assignment - 2, 3, 4).

Can someone explain to me what is the issue with the sketch?

```
const int PinA = 14; // Used for generating interrupts using CLK signal
const int PinB = 12; // Used for reading DT signal
const int PinSW = 13; // Used for the push button switch


int lCnt = 0; // Keep track of last rotary value
volatile int vPos = 0; // Updated by the ISR (Interrupt Service Routine)

void isr_event ()  {
  static unsigned long lIsrTmr = 0; // Last Interrupt time
  unsigned long IsrTmr = millis(); // Interrupt time

  // If interrupts come faster than 5ms, assume it's a bounce and ignore
  if (IsrTmr - lIsrTmr > 5) {
    if (digitalRead(PinB) == LOW)
    {
      vPos++ ; // Could be +5 or +10
    }
    else {
      vPos-- ; // Could be -5 or -10
    }

    // Restrict value from 0 to +100
    vPos = min(10, max(0, vPos));

    // Keep track of when we were here last (no more than every 5ms)
    lIsrTmr = IsrTmr;
  }
}

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);

  // Rotary pulses are INPUTs
  pinMode(PinA, INPUT);
  pinMode(PinB, INPUT);

  pinMode(PinSW, INPUT_PULLUP); // Switch is floating so use the in-built PULLUP so we don't need a resistor

  attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(PinA), isr_event, LOW); // Attach the routine to service the interrupts

  Serial.println(F("Starting..."));  // Ready to go!
}

void loop()
{

  // Is someone pressing the rotary switch?
  if ((!digitalRead(PinSW))) {
    vPos = 0;
    while (!digitalRead(PinSW))
      delay(10);
  }

  // If the current rotary switch position has changed then update everything
  if (vPos != lCnt) {
    // Write out to serial monitor the value and direction
    Serial.println(vPos);
    // Keep track of this new value
    lCnt = vPos ;
  }
}
```

Comment: Define "not work"... That phrase can mean anything from "jittery movement" to "the whole thing exploded and burned off my eyebrows".

Comment: @Majenko No, didn't exploded just not getting any output to the Serial monitor.

Comment: Not even the initial "Starting" message?

Comment: Yes, I get the message "Starting..."

Comment: To be sure 100%, I recompiled for Arduino Uno as we speak and tested with both Rotary Encoder type ( KY-040 and MJKDZ) and it's working as expected. But as I said, it's not outputing nothing except "Starting..." on ESP8266 platform. @Majenko

Answer (score 1):

The ESP8266 doesn't know what a "LOW" interrupt is.  You will have to change your code to use FALLING, RISING or CHANGE interrupts only.

Comment: Tried all of them, the FALLING gives me the best result, also I made pinMode(PinA, INPUT); and removed digitalPinToInterrupt(), and made PinB to be attachInterrupt, but the output is weird, there are duplicates and messed counts too. [link](https://s8.postimg.cc/6j9vs34hx/ser_output.png)

Comment: perhaps your debounce isn't - [perhaps this code can help](https://github.com/LennartHennigs/ESPRotary/blob/master/src/ESPRotary.cpp)

Comment: @JaromandaX tried that to and it's working really bad, skipping and messing numbers up